# Returning a string literal from an Enum

Tags: java, string, enums

I'm trying to use an Enum to set a finite list of possible distances, with the string being used as a cssSelector within a Selenium API method:

```
public enum DistanceFrom {

    FIVEMILES("a[data-reactid='.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$5.0']"),
    TENMILES("a['.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$10.0.2']"),
    TWENTYMILES("a['.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$20.0']"),
    THIRTYMILES("a['.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$30.0']");


    private String value;

    DistanceFrom(String value){
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

I use this in a test:

```
local.setDistance(DistanceFrom.FIVEMILES.toString());
```

In which setDistance is a fluent method within a page object:

```
  public LocalNewsPage setDistance(String value) {
    WebElement setDistanceButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(value));
    setDistanceButton.click();
    return this;
}
```

Why must I declare:

```
local.setDistance(DistanceFrom.FIVEMILES.toString());
```

And not be able to simply:

```
local.setDistance(DistanceFrom.FIVEMILES);
```

Comment: Because `setDistance` expects a `String`. If you want it to accept a `DistanceFrom` and use its `toString` method you have to explicitly override `setDistance` to accept it and use its `toString` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit the `setDistance` method, you can change it to accept a `DistanceFrom`:

```
public LocalNewsPage setDistance(DistanceFrom value) {
    WebElement setDistanceButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(value.toString()));
    setDistanceButton.click();
    return this;
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the enum values in `DistanceFrom` to `static final String`s:

```
public final class DistanceFrom {

    public static final String FIVEMILES = "a[data-reactid='.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$5.0']";
    public static final String TENMILES = "a['.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$10.0.2']";
    public static final String TWENTYMILES = "a['.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$20.0']";
    public static final String THIRTYMILES = "a['.2cr8yg16ohc.2.1.0.2:$30.0']";

    private DistanceFrom() {}
}
```

Comment: it was staring me in the face! Thank you.